# Cf Logs connections failed because connected host has failed to respond

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a problem with the cf log. If I'm using cf logs, I get the following error

> C:\Users\Z003PCEU> cf logs hello-spring-cloud *FAILED Error dialing
>   traffic controller server: dial tcp 139.25.25.200:4443: connectex: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected hos t has failed to respond.. Please ask your Cloud
>   Foundry Operator to check the platform configuration (traffic
>   controller is wss://doppler.sys.de.c
>   loudfoundry.it-platforms.net:4443).*

Using Curl to get access provides the following info


*Proxy error
503*

the proxy is only needed for communication outside the company.  Cf should net use it.

Removing the proxy from console results in

> Failed to connect to 10.0.0.17 port 4443: Connection refused

10.X.X.X is the cloud internal network.

Anyone an Idea?

Comment: Update. DNS was wrong. After changing the DNS. I get the Message. Empty response from curl. But still the same from Cf logs

Comment: cf curl /v2/apps/7a0c34f4-aa72-4eb2-8595-95079cb1df2f works.

Comment: Interesting. It works from within the cloud network. But not from the outside. Looks like a network problem.

Comment: Found it. The Firewall between my client pc and the Cloud lab is not configured to use Port 4443.

Comment: You should probably either delete this question, or answer it yourself.

Comment: @EngineerBetter Sorry I forget to give an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a firewall problem. The port 4443 was not open. After changing the configuration within the firewall it works